# Detecting if ISPs are blocking torrent download

Tags: utorrent

Up until this past month, I've had no problems downloading torrent files using  uTorrent. Now, neither magnet links nor .torrentfiles can download.

Is it possible that the ISP has started  blocking P2P traffic? Is there a way to detect this? (I mean finding out yourself and not asking the ISP directly. Would that even work?)

Comment: find out from your ISP

Comment: Enable encryption. ISP can only block traffic they known. I will bet this is a routing problem as almost no ISP completely cuts torrent traffic.

Comment: See this...http://dpi.ischool.syr.edu/MLab-Data.html

Comment: @P thx for sharing.  all your idea?

Comment: I also have this question. Can anyone help me by providing some new answers? The accepted answer no longer works, Switzerland requires more than one computer for its use, and Glasnost requires me to upload it to a server I control, when I want to test files and torrents hosted outside my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can port blocking from your isp with this site:

[What is my ip - Port Scanner](http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/)

but you can randomize port of torrent client that cause bypass specific port blocking from isp.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore as network monitoring software has incorporated learning algorithms into its detection strategy..

Comment: The website you link to doesn't work. The test is faulty. How can port 80 and 443 fail if I can visit websites in my web browser?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 software's you can run to attempt discovery of ISP bittorrent throttling.

[Switzerland Network Testing Tool](https://www.eff.org/pages/switzerland-network-testing-tool)

[Glasnost: Test if your ISP is shaping your traffic](http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/bttest.php)

[More reading](https://web.archive.org/web/20120616005112/http://dpi.ischool.syr.edu/MLab-Data.html)

Comment: As of Feburary 2017 Glasnost is no longer available. Glasnost is based on Java applet technology, which is no longer supported in modern browsers. Hence, after more than 8 years in operation we decided to shut down Glasnost.
https://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/bttest.php?